# Paramiko throughs error while transferring file from linux server to a directory [ERROR] IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/tmp/upload/

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, pysftp

I am trying to transfer a file from linux server to a directory which is Lambda. I am using Paramiko module. I am passing a directory like '/temp/upload/'

```
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/mmoradi2/data/' but it says as below in the cloud watch log.

[ERROR] IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/tmp/upload/'
```

I have no idea what is the problem. This is my code:

```
    import paramiko
    import pysftp

    cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys = None
    with pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=user, password=password, port=22, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    
        sftp.chdir(ftp_filepath)              
        for file in filesList:
             sftp_remote_path = (ftp_filepath + file)
             sftp.get(sftp_remote_path, localpath = '/temp/upload', preserve_mtime = True)
```

I was able to make the connection and successfully changed the directory using sftp.chdir(ftp_filepath)
but I am getting  `Is a directory: '/home/mmoradi2/data/' error`!

Can someone please help me to understand why it's failing

I have tried using get_d() also but getting same error!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're missing some context.  What is ```ftp_filepath```?  Assuming that it's ```/home/mmoradi2/data/```, according to https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/cookbook.html#pysftp-connection-get,  the ```localpath```  should be a  the directory + filename.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/53760297/850848